# Why wont json from mongodb show up on localhost:5000?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im trying to configure/connect mongodb to express but when go to localhost:5000/contacts it doesnt show up
im thinking the problem is with the uri but i cant be sure. Maybe incorrect syntax? Tehre are no error messgaes so i dont think i see what the problem is

route file:

```
    const router = require('express').Router()
    let Contacts = require('../models/contacts.model')
    
    router.route('/').get((req, res) =>  {
        Contacts.find()
            .then(contacts => res.json(contacts))
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err))
    });
    
    router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
        const name = req.body.name;
        const email = req.body.email;
        const phone =  Number(req.body.phone);
    
        const newContact = new Contacts({
            name,
            email,
            phone
        })
    
        newContact.save()
         .then(() => {res.json('Contacts added!')})
         .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err))
    })
    
    module.exports = router
```

and for the server js:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    
    require('dotenv').config();
    
    const app = express();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json())
    
    const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
    mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true});
    
    const connection = mongoose.connection;
    connection.once('open', () => {
        console.log("MongoDb database connection established succesfully")
    })
    
    const contactsRouter = require('./routes/contacts');
    app.use('/contacts', contactsRouter)
    
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
    })
```

Comment: Is there a route for '/Contacts'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one the problem might be server was not created.

```
    const http = require('http')
    const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose')
    
    require('dotenv').config();    
    const app = express();
    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json())
    
    const server = http.createServer(app);
    const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
  
   server.on('listening', () => {
    mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true});
    
     const connection = mongoose.connection;
     connection.once('open', () => {
         console.log("MongoDb database connection established succesfully")
      })
   })
    
    const contactsRouter = require('./routes/contacts');
    app.use('/contacts', contactsRouter)
    
    server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
    })
```

Comment: No worreis you just need to create server and server will listen your http/https requests. Please accept answer if you are satisfied